# How to apply cummulative count on multiple columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

**Dataframe**

```
    a   b   c
0   0   1   1
1   0   1   1
2   0   0   1
3   0   0   1
4   1   1   0
5   1   1   1
6   1   1   1
7   0   0   1
```

I am trying apply cummulative count `cumcount` on multiple columns of dataframe,  i have tried applying the cummulative count by grouping each column. Is there any easy way to achieve expected output

I have tried this code , but it is not working

```
li =[]
for column in df.columns:
    li.append(df.groupby(column)[column].cumcount())
pd.concat(li,axis=1)
```

**Expected output**

```
    a   b   c
0   1   1   1
1   1   2   2
2   1   1   3
3   1   1   4
4   1   1   1
5   2   2   1
6   3   3   2
7   1   1   3
```

Comment: Frst and last column is different in output data, can you explain more?

Comment: yes. If there is any 0 in a sequence of column , count of 1's should start from first onwards. all zeros should replace with 1's once count of 1's is assigned. @jezrael

Comment: tried to optimize it bit ;) , just added  @anky_91

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create consecutive groups by comparing with shifted values and for each column apply `cumcount`, last set `1` by boolean mask:

```
df = (df.ne(df.shift()).cumsum()
       .apply(lambda x: df.groupby(x).cumcount() + 1)
       .mask(df == 0, 1))
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  2  2
2  1  1  3
3  1  1  4
4  1  1  1
5  2  2  1
6  3  3  2
7  1  1  3
```

Another solution if performance is important - count only `1` values and last set `1` by mask by `np.where`:

```
a = df == 1
b = a.cumsum()
arr = np.where(a, b-b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int), 1)

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  2  2
2  1  1  3
3  1  1  4
4  1  1  1
5  2  2  1
6  3  3  2
7  1  1  3
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :-) @jezrael